# Showing Comments on Blog Post Details

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Currently I have a partial view that displays comments from the database associated with a certain blogid. I can't get this to work for the life of me. I can't even figure out how to pass the blogid to the partial so I pull the correct comments. Here is what I have so far.

/Blog/Details Comment Portion

```
<h2>Comments</h2>
<hr/>
@if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <p>You Must Be Logged In To Comment.</p>
} 
else
{
    @: Posting comments as @User.Identity.Name<hr/>
    @Html.Action("Create", "Comment", new {blogId = Model.Id}); 
    @: <hr/>
}
@Html.Partial("_Comments")
```

_Comments partial view

```
@model IEnumerable<GregG.Models.Comment>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    if (item.BlogId == 1) //I need to make this dynamic but can't figure out how to pass the id
    {
        <small>Posted by: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName) on:                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PostedDate)</small>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Meat)<hr/>
    }
}
```

My first question is: How do I pass my blog Id to the partial.
My second question is why do I receive this error on my partial line.

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Blog_18032B13AD6163845F0AE57E827683E3638FD813CA4EE066F28D05E5406E633D', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[GregG.Models.Comment]'.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There ares several overloads of the [`Patial`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee402902%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) method that support specifying the view model for the patial. Use this if the comments you want to display are already part of your current view model.

```
@Html.Partial("_Comments", Model.Comments)
```

However, if they are not part of your view model, I suggest creating a separate action in your `CommentController` and like this:

```
Action List(int blogId)
{
    // query comments from database
    var model = db.Comments.Where(c => c.BlogId == blogId);
    return View(model);
}
```

And calling it from your `/Blog/Details.cshtml` file like this:

```
@Html.Action("List", "Comment", new { blogId = Model.Id })
```

Comment: I ended up using the @Html.Action option and it worked perfectly thanks!